# Android Application change language when waking from sleep

Tags: android

I have problem, with my application. I'm giving users an option to change language. That works great using the following code:

```
public void jezik_slo(View view)
{
     Locale locale = new Locale("SI_sl");
     Locale.setDefault(locale);
     Configuration config = new Configuration();
     config.locale = locale;
     this.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
}

public void jezik_ang(View view)
{
     Locale locale = new Locale("en_US");
     Locale.setDefault(locale);
     Configuration config = new Configuration();
     config.locale = locale;
     this.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
}
```

Everything is ok, except when locking the phone, or if phone goes to sleep, and then waking up. At that point the application uses the DEFAULT string values(Values -EN)
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Two elements:
- Why have the parameter "View view" in the methods
- If you want to save a chosen language, you can save it somewhere. like in "SharedPreference":

add save method:

```
private static final String BASE_LANGUAGE = "base", KEY_LANGUAGE = "lang";

private void saveLanguage(String lang) {
SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences(BASE_LANGUAGE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putString(KEY_LANGUAGE, lang);
editor.commit();
}
```

add get method:

```
private String getLanguage() {
SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences(BASE_LANGUAGE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
return sp.getString(KEY_LANGUAGE, "en_US"); //en_US is default language
}
```

remove code duplication

```
public void jezik(String lang)
{
     Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
     Locale.setDefault(locale);
     Configuration config = new Configuration();
     config.locale = locale;
     this.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
     saveLanguage(lang);
}
```

to load the language, in "onCreate" method, try this:

```
jezik(getLanguage());
```

in this code "this" is Activity or Context. Sorry for my english, I hope this is what you want